# Good DLNA Server for Logitech Revue with DVD-ISO support?

Tags: linux, upnp, dlna, media-server

I'm looking for a good DLNA server to serve my media files on Linux to a Logitech Revue on the same network. I'm currently using `minidlna` which works great without a hitch, but it lacks support for DVD iso files, and I'd much rather be able to stream these over the network rather than ripped and reencoded MP4 videos as I'm currently doing. Does anyone know of a good solution for this?

I tried using PS3MediaServer, but my Logitech Revue can't even see it on the network whereas minidlna "just works." I don't need any complicated renderer functionality, I just need UPnP discovery and transfer of files over HTTP like minidlna does.

---

## EDIT

I also tried out MediaTomb, but the Logitech Revue doesn't seem to like it. I can see it on the network, but cannot browse it (I get a generic Network Error message when trying to do so.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, the answer is no, there isn't really a solution out there. The Revue depends on functionality that isn't technically required by the UPnP ContentDirectory spec, so it simply does not work with most servers. It looks like `minidlna` is the solution right now, at least until I build my own server from the ground up.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked whether my favourite DLNA server ([Serviio](http://www.serviio.org/)) would do ISOs, but it won't :-(

But...someone had already asked about this in their forums and [Wizd media server](http://wizd.sourceforge.net/) was mentioned. I've never used it but it may be worth a look.

Wizd is serving all your media (video, audio, photo...) to your networked player.

- automatically detected by your player
- browse faster than ever through your media
- no aditionnal server required (Apache, PHP...)
- low memory usage (less than 10 MB)
- fully customizable (skins and settings)
- read DVD-ISO backups and standard DVD backups
- bookmark feature for MPEG movies
- tumbnails mode to preview your pictures
- free and open-source :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm running 64bit Linux and they don't offer a 64bit installer. I also can't seem to execute the static binary they offer. I've tried using `getlibs` to install it, but it's not really working at all. :(

Comment: I was able, however to run it in Wine, but it didn't show up in the network at all.

Answer (score 1):

NETGEAR NEOTV550 (a media center box) plays shared DVD/Blu-ray images as they are with full menu support. No Netflix though.

Answer (score 0):

Amahi might work out for you.

This one user had luck with the Revue, not sure about ISO files though.
http://blog.amahi.org/2011/02/03/the-drought-is-nearly-over-amahi-6-beta-torrent-of-app-updates/#comment-525853

http://www.amahi.org